# Update metadata of many items in library

Tags: powershell, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, document-set, pnp-powershell

I have the requirement, that the values for two of my site columns of all our document libraries depend on a value outside of SharePoint (its stored in a database).
If the value in the database changes, the metadata value in SharePoint should also be changed.
What I did until today is creating a document set and changing the shared metadata property via REST. This works perfectly, because I just need a single REST-Call per library.
But we want to use the new experience of libraries and document sets do not support this look yet.

So what other ways do I have if I want to update a lot of metadata of one column in my libraries?

One method would be to iterate all items via REST and change every single one. This approach however takes thousands of calls, one for each file, and is therefore not practicable.

Another way would be to use a PowerShell Skript or the new SPO-Cmdlets via SharePoint Shell. But in this case I have to retrieve every single item also, right? Or is there a way to do batch operations faster?

A third way could be a SharePoint workflow that runs every time someone does a change to the document library.
I could abuse the library description to store the metadata for the two fields there as a JSON-Object and the workflow just parses the description field and sets the metadata.

And then there could be a JavaScript solution on SharePoint site.

Well... the workflow might work, but how would you solve such a problem? If I had an On Premise environment I could use a Full-Trust solution to just iterate over my items on server side, what would be a lot quicker.

Any proposals what I could do?